# Add-Account not working, no subscription associated even if I'm global admin in portal

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-server-2016

I'm unable to run Azure Powershell commands, as of now I'm trying to assign a static local IP to my VM by doing so:

> Get-AzureVM -ServiceName XenApp-Azure -Name XenApp-Azure |
> Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress 10.0.0.4 | Update-AzureVM

This command tells me

> No default subscription has been designated. Use
> Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the
> default subscription.

To which I've tried both below

> Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName Pay-As-You-Go
>
> Select-AzureSubscription -Default Pay-As-You-Go

Both command tell me that subscription doesn't not exist, even though this:

> Login-AzureRmAccount

Returns this after a successful login:

```
Account          : myuser@domain.tv
SubscriptionName : Pay-As-You-Go
SubscriptionId   : guid
TenantId         : guid
Environment      : AzureCloud
```

To which I've tried:

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

Which returns:

> No subscriptions are associated with the logged in account in Azure
> Service Management (RDFE). This means that the logged in user is not
> an  administrator or co-administrator for any account.\r\nDid you mean
> to execute Login-AzureRmAccount?

Which is non sense because I created the VM through the Azure portal and I have enough access to be remoted in through RDP. I am owner of this "non-existing" subscription.

What is happening here ?

Comment: Are you able to go on : https://manage.windowsazure.com  and view the machine ? Are you in the Service administrator and/or co-administrator group of your subscription ? You might be global administrator on the portal.azure.com user interface but if you did not have at all a classic subscription tied to your account or not enough right, this could happens. This happened to me. Can you confirm you can access to https://manage.windowsazure.com go in the settings and see you listed as Service administrator and/or co-administrator ?

Comment: Try Select-AzureRMSubscription instead of the Select-AzureSubscription after Login-AzureRMAccount. The non-RM version of the cmdlet are for the classic interfaces / resources. Also, is your VM a classic or ARM deployment ?

Comment: Which version of your Azure PowerShell? please run this command to check it. `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`.

Comment: Does this issue solved? please let me know if you need more help:)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to be the Admin or Co-admin for the subscription.
Ask the admin to add you as co-admin and then try running the scripts.